# how can i put input() function into a def fonction in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

I am working on a collatz sequence that i have found in a book and i want to input the number but it dosen t work , when i put the number the enter keybord key does not work , have i made something wrong in my program ? :

```
even = range(0,10**5,2)
odd = range(1,10**5,2)

def collatz_s(num):
    while num !=1 :
        if num in even :
            result = num /2
            print(result)
            num = result

        elif num is odd :
            result = num *3+1
            num = result
            print(result)


num = int(input('choose a random number'))
collatz_s(num)
```

Comment: please clarify the question. what do you suspect is the problem? what did you try to counter that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether a number is odd or even,  rather than generating `range` objects and checking whether a number is `in` them, look at the remainder in the division by two, which you can get with `num % 2`. If the remained is 1, it means the number is even. Otherwise, it's odd.

Also, use `num // 2` to perform an *integer* division. That way dividing 16 by 2 will give you 8 (the integer number), instead of 8.0 (the floating point number.) It turns out this is really important here, especially since you're interested in finding the remainder of the division (a concept mainly concerning integer numbers.)

I believe it's quite possible that a rounding error in the floating point division might have put your program into an infinite loop (since a number with a tiny decimal part would not be in either `even` or `odd` range.) Or if you were surpassing the limit of your ranges (10<sup>5</sup>) you'd be in the same situation where neither branch matches. Using integer division and checking for even or odd using the remainder should fix both issues.

```
def collatz_s(num):
    while num != 1:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = num // 2
            print(num)
        else:
            num = num * 3 + 1
            print(num)
```

Comment: What you say about ranges is absolutely not true in Python 3. I can do `5 * 10**19 in range(0, 10**20, 2)` and get an immediate answer - no way is it iterating through that many values. (In Python 2 what you say would be correct, but the question explicitly says Python 3.)

Comment: That said, obviously I agree that your test is better, because the OP's use of ranges imposes arbitrary limits on the range within which the number must fall (or it will neither be in `even` nor `odd`). But your statements about expensiveness should be removed.

Comment: @alani Yes you're right, there's a special `__contains__` method that makes that possible without iterating through the list. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @filbranden **there is no list**. `range` objects have constant-time membership testing for int objects. They are also constant space, but your overall advice is good

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Updated the answer to address that. Thanks!

Comment: this method is really working in big numbers thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your `elif` block, here `elif num is odd :` change `is` to `in` when dealing with remainder use `integer division(//)` instead to avoid `precision` error .

```
def collatz_s(num):
    while num != 1:
        if num in even:
            result = num // 2
            print(result)
            num = result

        elif num in odd:
            result = num * 3 + 1
            print(result)
            num = result



num = int(input('choose a random number'))
collatz_s(num) 
# input 5
# output 

16
8
4
2
1
```

Comment: yes it is working now but the program does not support big numbers

Comment: it will support big number but will take a long long time. Think some efficient way.

Comment: @Tasnuva if you are referencing `in odd` and `in even` it's already constant time, range objects have constant-time membership checking

Comment: @YassineRemmal that's because you use a fixed amount for your even and odd. This isn't the normal way to check if something is even or odd, you should use `number % 2`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thing is every time he is iterating over list. So it gonna be more time consuming.

Comment: @Tasnuva no, it isn't iterating over it, *it isn't a `list` object* it is a `range` object, which implements constant-time membership tests for `int` objects